# Common Lisp Compile and Load Directory

Tags: compilation, macros, lisp, common-lisp

I am wondering how I can re-compile and load all `.lisp` files in a certain directory. I have modified a macro that is heavily used by all the files in that directory. Hence, it would be most efficient to just re-compile and re-load the entire thing.

If it helps, I am doing this on Allegro, but am curious about the same for SBCL.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a [system construction facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)). like [`asdf`](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/).

Any ad hoc code you might whip up is not worth the effort. Just write a small `asd` file for this directory.

Comment: I use ASDF. However, on this project, we do not have it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why not? it should be quite easy to install (https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/#downloads)